# Views & Filter criteria

Tags: views

I've got a filter criteria saying field xyz = NO. Old nodes meeting the criteria above do not get picked up by the filter. When I edit the node, and resave it, only then they appear in the view. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. You will have to create two or more filter groups which will be separated with an OR condition.

Click "And/Or, Rearrange Filter Criteria" from the drop down menu of the Filters section and then click "Create New Filter Group". After that drag the filters you want in the new filter group and change the condition separating the groups to OR from AND. I would do it as follows:

**1st group**

Content: Published Yes And

Content: Type = News And

Content: Xyz (xyz) = Yes

**OR**

**2nd Group**

Content: Published Yes And

Content: Type = News And

Content: abc (abc) = Yes

Comment: Thank you @Billy-kouroublakis!

I did eventually try that, but the view only seems to be picking up the newly created or edited nodes. Is this normal? Once you change the field name in the content type, does this change the database in such a way that i need to edit every single node and redo all the selections?

Oh, how can I have the same filter in more than one group? I can only move them between groups, cant copy them :S

Comment: 1) No that's not normal unless you have added a node post date filter or a content:new filter or maybe it's a pager issue. 2) You can have the same filter by simply adding that filter again and dragging to a different filter group.

Comment: 3) Of course not. Changing the field name in the content type does not require you to change it for every node in the database.

Comment: Thanks again @Billy

I've got a filter criteria saying field xyz = NO.

Old nodes meeting the criteria above do not get picked up by the filter. When I edit the node, and resave it, only then they appear in the view.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @kine456 Did you add the field `xyz` _after_ you already had nodes of the content type whith the new field created? Nodes created before new fields are added will not have a field value, and `NULL` is not equal to `NO (FALSE)`. If this is your issue, you need to either choose to count NULL values as TRUE or FALSE. FALSE, or NO, would probably be the most logical choice.